# How to show content of variables in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

In many cases xCode does not show the content of the variables when I move the mouse over them.

Is there an alternative way to show the content?

For example of simple bytes, arrays of bytes, ...
Is there a way to specify the output format somehow?

Comment: At the debugger console: `(lldb) p <variable name>` or `po <object variable name>` (for primitives and Objective-C objects, respectively).

Comment: thanks - and is there a way to actually drill down if I have an array of objects for example somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now much improved variable formatting via the lldb debugger, where you can specify the formatting for your own types. Read the [docs](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html) on how to specify these, then put them in a python script and in `~/.lldbinit` add the line:

```
command script import path/to/my/formatters.py
```

For more information on LLDB data formatters see:

- http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html
- http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/synthetic/ - has examples for STL formatters
- look at the bundled scripts in `Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/formatters`

Answer (score 1):

Some times Xcode doesn't show the content when place mouse over the variable.for getting the value you can write like `po (variable name )` in console.
[once check this one](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/02/debugging-objective-c-objects-in-gdb-using-po/)

Comment: Thanks, but I guess there is something wrong either with my xcode or something else??? When I type in the console:(lldb) po (foundFaultCodes), where "foundFaultCodes" is my variable - nothing happens for quite a while- then with delay of longer than a minute suddendly it shows the value - is this normal?

Comment: also, is there a way to drill down, for example inspect an object if I get back sth like this $0 = 0x20152b50 <__NSArrayM 0x20152b50>(

) - ps I had to restart xCode several times now and even reboot the machine - is it really that unstable?

Comment: once check above link.